# kubectl start after reboot using service

Tags: linux, services, suse, kubernetes

I need your help.

I want to execute this command after reboot of the server with delay as a service. I am using SUSE linux on this machine.

The command I need to run works well

`kubectl --namespace kasten-io port-forward --address localhost,xx.xxx.xxx.xxx service/gateway 8080:8000 &`

So I created the script

```
sleep 5
kubectl --namespace kasten-io port-forward --address localhost,xx.xxx.xxx.xxx service/gateway 8080:8000 &
```

and the service

```
[Unit]
Description=Kubectl port forwarding

[Service]
#User=root
#WorkingDirectory=/root
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /root/kasten_port_forward.sh
#Restart=always


[Install]
#WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=default.target
```

When I enable and start the service it doesnt run the the command for kubectl.
I added some `touch /root/file` to test if it is running. Everything works but kubectl command is skipped for some reason.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What does it run when you start the service?

Comment: Anything checking journald logs for that unit? Tried adding set -x to confirm your commands are properly formatted? Also: why would you do this?! kubectl port-forward is meant to help during troubleshooting/tests/..., rather than expose a service indefinitely.